# Representing duration on a map

Tags: data-visualization

I have a geographical map of a region, with a few locations of interest on it. For these locations (a dozen - edit: I just counted them, they are actually 25! Sorry for the underestimation), I want to represent how long people stay there, on average.

What is the best way to represent duration?

I was thinking about using circles  with either **size** representing duration (longer the duration, larger the circle), or **color** (longer the duration, stronger the color). I think color may be the best option, because size may let think the circle represents a number of people.

Is using color OK? Am I overthinking the issue with using size? Are there better options than those two?

If it can help, the difference of average duration between locations can range from a couple of weeks up to six months.

After I posted my initial question above, Whuber gave very useful information in  comments, but also pointed out that additional context is needed to answer it. Here is some additional information (I think I can't give much more info than that, but will try if needed) :

This is for representing the average duration of detention for a minor criminal offense, in a dozen of prisons in a certain region (I just calculated very roughly the area, it is about 89,000 square kilometers) . Two prisons are quite close to each other (distant of 2 km), but the rest are more scattered, with the next closest distance between two prisons being about 50 km. The prison most distant from others is about 100 km from its closest "neighbor". In other words, distances between prisons range from 50 to 100 km, except for two prisons that are distant of 2 km.

The audience will be mainly academic (this is my intended audience), but some professionals and some people from the general public might see it too, though I think the map will be of interest only to very few people.

The intended purpose of the map is to highlight the differences of duration between prisons, and also show there's a geographical pattern (durations are clearly longer in a few prisons that belong to a specific part of the region.)

Thank you.

Comment: the only way forward here is to try both see how they look.

Comment: Neither area nor color are the first choices one would experiment with.  How you approach this depends on your intended audience, the numbers and density of the locations, and what message you wish to send.  Without such information there's little anyone can *objectively* say.  Your options range from tabulating the data, posting the data on the map, erecting simple bars to represent duration, using the brightness of symbols to represent duration, and only then would color (hue) be worth considering.  Often, redundancy helps: you aren't limited to one method at a time.